# Highcharts - How to detect when a dataLabel is not visible?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a requirement using Highcharts where I have stacked column graphs with data attached to jquery sliders. When someone moves the slider the data in the graphs update and the graphs redraw. There may be a situation when the data in the graph is so small the data label is too big to fit inside the column and what I want to do is remove all the data labels from that column and then draw an overlay with the data value in it.

I've been trawling the Highcharts documentation and I can't find an event or anything that I can attach to that detects when a dataLabel is overflowing.

Does anyone know how I could approach this?

Thanks
Glenn

Comment: Generally you can use a column size and compare with datalabel box, but we need a live demo (like jsfiddle).

Comment: @SebastianBochan For example: http://jsfiddle.net/6oc0x50h/1/